# Angular JS validation step by step is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have started to get into Angular JS validation....

I have this step:

```
<step title="Let's begin with some information about your business">
          <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td><label>Your Name</label></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="user.name" required /></td>
              </tr>
</table>
</form>
</step>
```

and I have this button outside of the steps...outside of the wizard:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gotoNextStep()" ng-show="showNextButton()">Next</a>
```

and in my js file, I have this function called on ng-click:

```
   $scope.gotoNextStep = function () {
          if ($scope.currentStepIndex == (3)) {
              $scope.submitForm = function (isValid) {
                  if (isValid) {
                      toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1);
                  }
              };
          } else {
              toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1);
          }
      }
```

what I am trying to do is prevent the user from going to the next step until the required field is filled.

just before my step ends and after the form ends I added this `<p>{{myForm.$invalid}}</p>` and it appears as true, if I change it to valid it returns false. So it seems like this is kinda working except I cant provent my user from going to the next page.

Currently with this code, the button does not goto the next step even if the required field is filled in or not. Please Help.

I should also note that $scope.submitForm is saying its undefined :(

Another note.. {{myForm.$valid}} returns false but when I fill out the required field it returns true....how would I use myForm.$valid in the js file for the $scope.gotoNextStep function

Comment: We need to see some more code. Where's your directive? Where is the `toggleSteps` code?

Comment: Hi, I put all my js code here: http://jsfiddle.net/sK79f/1/ its a bit messy, but the toggleSteps and both of my directive are there

Comment: That JSFiddle has no HTML.

Comment: try now: http://jsfiddle.net/sK79f/2/ I can never get angular JS to work in JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Could you use ng-disabled in your button? Like this:

```
<a ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine || myForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gotoNextStep()" ng-show="showNextButton()">Next</a>
```

And then get rid of the ng-submit in the form tag. I also just noticed you have novalidate on your form. You should remove that too.